# navigation between screens Iphone programming

Tags: iphone, navigation, screen

I don't know if my question will be clear or not, but i'm starting basic stuff with iphone programming, and i'm trying to understand how to go from a screen to another.
lets say i have a screen with a "next page" button  and another page with a "return" button.
I have a general idea of how to do this, but I don't know how to put it together.
I think I need an IBAction method for each button, and in each method a navigation controller with pushViewController. So far, i've tried the following code, but even if it compiles properly and runs when i push the button, there is no change of screen...

```
-(IBAction) toNext(id)sender{
NSLog(@"before code");
NextViewController *nvc = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];
[nvc release];
NSLog(@"after code");
}
```

If someone had a nice tuto for me, it could be of some help...
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code won't work if your view controller (and it's not clear that you are even doing this from a view controller) doesn't have a navigationcontroller.

Secondly, you should pop to return, not push a second time.

There are different ways of moving between views.  The simplest is to call addSubview: with a view, which can be seen in the app delegate code of any app created from a template.

The two others are the push/pop used with navigation controllers (typically from a view controller), and present modal, which has to be called with a view controller as well.  The differences with these latter two are the animations used, and the assumption of how the views will be navigated away from.

Comment: thanks for your answer paul. Im actually doing this from my first viewcontroller.m file.
but then, how would you do with a navigationController? I have some trouble understanding the way these things work...I'm more a java programmer, and i'm starting with Objective C...

Comment: My suggestion is that you download Apple's UICatalog example and look through it.  This isn't an obj issue, it is a very simple (and very good) language - it is just a matter of becoming familiar with the cocoa-touch idioms.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to implement a navigation based application in iPhone [Navigation Application][1]

[1]: http://theappleblog.com/2009/04/15/iphone-dev-sessions-create-a-navigation-based-application/ just go though it may be this is what you are looking for

Comment: thanks for this tuto, but I know how to navigate from a tableView to the detail of a row. What i'm trying to do is going from my first view to my tableview... and i can't get it to work when i think it like the TableView...